# Why ruby on rails link_to redirect to itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes, rubymine

Lets say I have a controler test.

In test I define 3 actions:

```
def zah
end
def zeh
end
def zih
end
```

I have the views:

zah.html.erb

zeh.html.erb

zih.html.erb

and under routes.rb I have:

```
get 'test/zah'
get 'test/zeh'
get 'test/zih'
```

If I write under zah.html.erb, using code automaticaly created from rubymine IDE, this:

```
<%= link_to test_zeh_path%>
```

I will get my page source code with this:

```
<a href="/test/zah">http://localhost:3000/test/zeh</a>
```

which makes the redirection from zah be itself.

running rake routes returns this:

```
      Prefix Verb URI Pattern                 Controller#Action

    test_zah GET  /test/zah(.:format)         test#zah
    test_zeh GET  /test/zeh(.:format)         test#zeh
    test_zih GET  /test/zih(.:format)         test#zih
```

Can anyone explain to me why is the link going to itself (from zah to zah) instead of another page(from zah to zeh)?

Edit:

I have found out that adding a name to a link makes the generated code works right:

```
<%= link_to 'zeh', test_zeh_path%>
```

I have seen the first usage (link_to test_zeh_path) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E68pK6uhYpY&index=3&list=PLSXDqiI4sC5PsASjJy7dBncALnhjud2fx) at 22:45.

[Ruby on rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) does says that if nil name is passed then "the value of the link itself will become the name.".

As for a mistake of myself I was wondering why Dave Jones was able to create a link without a name, but he wasnt and that can be seen on his source code.

Comment: Where do you expect it to go?

Comment: I expect it to go from zah to zeh, but its pointing to zah instead.
link_to test_zeh_path should create a link to zeh and not zah.

Comment: @jpriebe I added some new informations.

Comment: Strange... glad you got it working. Sorry I can't offer any explanation as to why.

Comment: Sorry @jpriebe, I found out why. It was a lack of attention of myself. I'm unsure if should I delete this question or leave it here to help anyone who find it by not paying attention as I did.

Answer (score -1):

Because you have written the url in the display part.

You can simply do
`<%= link_to 'Goto Zeh', test_zeh_path %>`
and you will be good to go.